# Is it possible to show multiple HTML file contents in a HTML page at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show multiple HTML files in a HTML file at the same time, like how php blogs use templates.

For example I have 3 html pages: `head.htm`, `content.htm` and `footer.htm`. Another HTML page (`Post.html`) will display all the other pages in one.

Will it work with a combination of js and HTML? I don't wish to use php and html5 because, my host is static.

Edit : Question is answered now . Go down and you will see the solution.

Comment: You might be interested in a static site generator like [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) or [pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/)

Comment: I'm not interested in it ! They need to regenerate and re-deploy every generated files if I made some changes in the footer or header ( say a change in the link of an advertisements). That is too hard for me

Comment: check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486636/do-i-have-to-rewrite-an-html-header-everytime-i-want-to-use-it/31486690#31486690

Comment: HTML5 has nothing to do with your host’s capabilities. HTML5 is the markup served for clients, and is only dependent on your client’s capabilities (All modern browsers are quite capable).

Comment: If the content is static, put it in one page and use CSS and script to hide or show bits as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link ( [Do I have to rewrite an html header everytime I want to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486636/do-i-have-to-rewrite-an-html-header-everytime-i-want-to-use-it/31486690#31486690) ) will show you how to do that .

Thank you @Shehary and @floor for the best answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery. It has a method .load() http://api.jquery.com/load/

This will allow you to load html files.

```
$(function() {
      $('body').load('header.html');
});
```